# Design Pattern to Persist Filter Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, session-variables

I would like some suggestions on the proper design pattern or method to solve an issue I’m having.

Basically, in MVC3, I have a controller that has multiple actions that all simply generate table data.  Most (but not all) actions should have an optional year value that filters the results based on a selected year.  Currently, I am accepting the year value via querystring but if it’s not provided (or not valid) then defaults to the current year.

I was thinking of creating simple action method that allows the user to change the year via a select list, posts the selected value (and the current page) to an action which sets the selected year to a session variable (after validation) and redirects the user back to the page they were on.  Then for all subsequent requests, in the controller constructor I would have the year read back from the session variable and stored in a local variable which can then be used in each action.

However, I hesitant to go this approach as there are many references (many on this site) that warn about using session variables in the controller constructor.  I can continue to pass the year as a querystring parameter in each method, but the following is a snippit of code from one action that shows how I validate this year and duplicating this in each action seems a violation of the DRY principle.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

```
public ActionResult FundsAppropriationList(int? year = null)
{
  var fundsAppropriationListModel = new FundsAppropriationListModel(); 
  if (year != null && year >= 2000 && year <= 2099)
  {
    fundsAppropriationListModel.SelectedYear = (int)year;
  }
  else
  {
    fundsAppropriationListModel.SelectedYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
  }
  fundsAppropriationListModel.AvailableYearsList = new SelectList(_grantReviewServices.GetYearsForWhichReviewsExist().Select(x => new {value = x, text = x}), "value", "text");
  //... Remainder of model population here...
  return PartialView("_FundsAppropriationList", fundsAppropriationListModel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you have to duplicate that code in each action? Couldn't you just encapsulate the repeating code into its own method? Something like this:

```
public ActionResult FundsAppropriationList(int? year = null)
{
  var fundsAppropriationListModel = new FundsAppropriationListModel(); 

  fundsAppropriationListModel.SelectedYear = AssignYear(year);

  fundsAppropriationListModel.AvailableYearsList = new SelectList(_grantReviewServices.GetYearsForWhichReviewsExist().Select(x => new {value = x, text = x}), "value", "text");
  //... Remainder of model population here...
  return PartialView("_FundsAppropriationList", fundsAppropriationListModel);
}
```

The "duplicate" code:

```
internal static int AssignYear(int? year = null)
{
  if (year != null && year >= 2000 && year <= 2099)
  {
    return (int)year;
  }

  return DateTime.Now.Year;
}
```

Comment: Yea, that's what I ended up doing.  It just had a slight "smell" that I have to call the same method in each action.  I just thought that there might be a better way to tell the controller "each action will need this data configured, so do it for me when the controller is instantiated".  Regardless, thanks for feedback.